# How to join two json objects based on index in Groovy script?

Tags: json, groovy, apache-nifi

Am having two json files.

one is **InputFile.json:**

```
[{"no":"48","name":"Mahe","Age":"23"},
{"no":"49","name":"Siva","Age":"23"},
{"no":"50","name":"prabhu","Age":"37"}]
```

Another one is **Result.json**

```
{"results":"[
{"Grade":"4","Result":"PASS"},
{"Grade":"5","Result":"FAIL"},
{"Grade":"6","Result":"PASS"}]"
}
```

In that json i need to combine those two json like below..,

```
[{"no":"48","name":"Mahe","Age":"23","Grade":"4","Result":"PASS"},
{"no":"49","name":"Siva","Age":"23","Grade":"5","Result":"FAIL"},
{"no":"50","name":"prabhu","Age":"37","Grade":"6","Result":"PASS"}]
```

Based on index results[0] will be joined with InputFile[0].

Now i have tried to do it in Groovy(ExecuteScript) NiFi.

Am not able to get "4","5","6" Grade indexes from Result.json.

Tried code in which answered.

```
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()

def input = slurper.parse(inputFile)
def res = slurper.parse(result)

def joined = [input, res.results].transpose().collect { a, b -> a + b }
```

Am getting below issue.

```
groovy.json.JsonException: expecting '}' or ',' but got current char 'G' with an int value of 71

The current character read is 'G' with an int value of 71
expecting '}' or ',' but got current char 'G' with an int value of 71
line number 2
index number 17
{"Grade":"4","Result":"PASS"},
..^
```

Can any one suggest me the way to combine those two json in NiFi?

Comment: That seems to show what you're trying to read isn't valid json... Can you post the full file?

Comment: No. i have tried with InputFile.json and Result.json only attached in my question

Comment: Ahhhh `results` is a String containing Json inside a json document...  Weird...  If you can, I'd fix that, but if you can't, I've updated my answer

Comment: @tim_yates,Great help. it worked

Comment: @tim_yates Is this possible to add "Grade" only to InputFile.json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `JsonSlurper` and `transpose`

```
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()

def input = slurper.parse(inputFile)
def res = slurper.parse(result)

def joined = [input, res.results].transpose().collect { a, b -> a + b }
```

Ahhh, I see... in your example, the `results` is wrapped n a String for some reason....so we need to re-parse that string as json

This should work in this situation:

```
def input = slurper.parse(inputFile)
def res = slurper.parseText(slurper.parse(result).results)

def joined = [input, res].transpose().collect { a, b -> a + b }
```

Comment: Nice to know simple way to join.

Comment: It works for the example you have in your question doesn't it?

Comment: Am getting issue while reading that json. I will attach issue in my question